# Create file from BLOB with app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a Document in Google Drive from a BLOB generated from another document.
I've tried this simple example :

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/[My document]/edit");
  var docContentBlob = doc.getBlob();

  var newDocBlob = Utilities.newBlob(
    docContentBlob.getDataAsString(),
    "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    "TEST DOC BLOB");
```

This script create a document, but I can't open it (it display 'Loading, please wait' when I try to open the document and It never opens.

Why this script don't work?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but (1) newBlob doesn't create a document - is there more code you left out and (2) why are you starting with a blob and creating a new one? That is meaningless, and your syntax is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure either (as Corey already said) what you are trying to do but when you have a blob coming from a document (meaning a Google document in this context) you can only (at least that I'm thinking of now) use DocsList to create something "new" from that blob... and it won't be a Google document but a pdf file instead !

If you want to get a copy of a doc simply use makeCopy from the docsList service.

Here is a piece of code to illustrate both possibilities :

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/[My document ID]/edit");
  var docContentBlob = doc.getBlob();
  var copyofDoc = DocsList.getFileById(doc.getId()).makeCopy('new copy of '+doc.getName());// this will create a copy (google doc format)
  var newDocfromBlob = DocsList.createFile(docContentBlob);// this will create a pdf version of your doc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mime type of the file so that Google knows how to display / open it.